# how to intgrate power bi report to react app with public access and withoud need to authanticate

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powerbi

i have a power bi report on power bi service which is not that much sensitive, I want to intgrate it to my react app which would be a public app on web.

i need it to be embedded in a way where it hust dosent ask users for authentication

i have tried using publish to web method, it kind of worked